# python colorama print all colors

Tags: python, properties, colorama

I am new to learning Python, and I came across colorama. As a test project, I wanted to print out all the available colors in colorama.

```
from colorama import Fore
from colorama import init as colorama_init

colorama_init(autoreset=True)

colors = [x for x in dir(Fore) if x[0] != "_"]
for color  in colors:
    print(color + f"{color}")
```

of course this outputs all black output like this:

```
BLACKBLACK
BLUEBLUE
CYANCYAN
...
```

because the Dir(Fore) just gives me a string representation of `Fore.BLUE`, `Fore.GREEN`, ...

Is there a way to access all the Fore Color property so they actually work, as in:

```
print(Fore.BLUE + "Blue")
```

**Or in other words, this may express my problem better.**

I wanted to write this:

```
print(Fore.BLACK + 'BLACK')
print(Fore.BLUE + 'BLUE')
print(Fore.CYAN + 'CYAN')
print(Fore.GREEN + 'GREEN')
print(Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX + 'LIGHTBLACK_EX')
print(Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX + 'LIGHTBLUE_EX')
print(Fore.LIGHTCYAN_EX + 'LIGHTCYAN_EX')
print(Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + 'LIGHTGREEN_EX')
print(Fore.LIGHTMAGENTA_EX + 'LIGHTMAGENTA_EX')
print(Fore.LIGHTRED_EX + 'LIGHTRED_EX')
print(Fore.LIGHTWHITE_EX + 'LIGHTWHITE_EX')
print(Fore.LIGHTYELLOW_EX + 'LIGHTYELLOW_EX')
print(Fore.MAGENTA + 'MAGENTA')
print(Fore.RED + 'RED')
print(Fore.RESET + 'RESET')
print(Fore.WHITE + 'WHITE')
print(Fore.YELLOW + 'YELLOW')
```

in a shorter way:

```
for color in all_the_colors_that_are_available_in_Fore:
    print('the word color in the representing color')
    #or something like this?
    print(Fore.color + color)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason why it's printing the color name twice is well described in Patrick's comment on the question.

`Is their a way to access all the Fore Color property so they actualy work as in`

According to: https://pypi.org/project/colorama/

You can print a colored string using other ways than e.g.`print(Fore.RED + 'some red text')`

You can use [colored](https://pypi.org/project/termcolor/) function from `termcolor` module which takes a string and a color to colorize that string. But not all `Fore` colors are supported so you can do the following:

```
from colorama import Fore
from colorama import init as colorama_init
from termcolor import colored

colorama_init(autoreset=True)

colors = [x for x in dir(Fore) if x[0] != "_"]
colors = [i for i in colors if i not in ["BLACK", "RESET"] and "LIGHT" not in i] 

for color  in colors:
    print(colored(color, color.lower()))
```

Hope this answered your question.

EDIT:

I read more about `Fore` items and I found that you can retrieve a dictionary containing each color as keys and it's code as values, so you can do the following to include all the colors in `Fore`:

```
from colorama import Fore
from colorama import init as colorama_init

colorama_init(autoreset=True)

colors = dict(Fore.__dict__.items())

for color in colors.keys():
    print(colors[color] + f"{color}")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and it works good. But not for all the colors. Like the LIGHT colors for example.

Comment: I just edited my answer to solve that, please check it :)

Comment: Hi Can you tell me how can I add custom colors in it? Like I want to use Orange and Grey but it's not there

Comment: @AbdulHaseeb In this case you have to use colors codes, check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-to-print-colored-text-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use eval().

```
for i in listOfColors:
    color = "Fore." + i
    print(eval(color), i)
    print(Style.RESET_ALL, end='') #end='' prevents extra newlines
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the *getattr* function.

```
from colorama import Fore
from colorama import init as colorama_init

colorama_init(autoreset=True)

colors = [x for x in dir(Fore) if x[0] != "_" and "LIGHT" not in x]
for color in colors:
    print(getattr(Fore, color) + f"{color}")
```