# In for loops, is there a way to execute a module function with attributes assigned by the for loop?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, attributes, colorama

Python 3.10.1

Totally new to programming, please be patient.

I want to print a list of all foreground colors available in the `colorama` module in the color named, like so:

[PowerShell Colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRBgi.png)

My attempt:

```
from colorama import init, Fore, Style
init()

# available foreground colors acquired via dir(Fore)
colors = [
    'BLACK',
    'BLUE',
    'CYAN',
    'GREEN',
    'LIGHTBLACK_EX',
    'LIGHTBLUE_EX',
    'LIGHTCYAN_EX',
    'LIGHTGREEN_EX',
    'LIGHTMAGENTA_EX',
    'LIGHTRED_EX',
    'LIGHTWHITE_EX',
    'LIGHTYELLOW_EX',
    'MAGENTA',
    'RED',
    'WHITE',
    'YELLOW'
]

for col in colors:
    fcol = "Fore." + col
    print(f"  {exec(fcol)}[{col}]{Style.RESET_ALL}")
```

My output (no color changes):

```
  None[BLACK]
  None[BLUE]
  None[CYAN]
  None[GREEN]
  None[LIGHTBLACK_EX]
  None[LIGHTBLUE_EX]
  None[LIGHTCYAN_EX]
  None[LIGHTGREEN_EX]
  None[LIGHTMAGENTA_EX]
  None[LIGHTRED_EX]
  None[LIGHTWHITE_EX]
  None[LIGHTYELLOW_EX]
  None[MAGENTA]
  None[RED]
  None[WHITE]
  None[YELLOW]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, I searched around some more and found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61687509/18130981) by user Kasper I couldn't before, which I implemented to my code like so:

```
from colorama import init, Fore, Style
init()

colors = dict(Fore.__dict__.items())

for color in colors.keys():
    print(colors[color] + f"  [{color}]")
```

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is when you assign:

```
"Fore." + col
```

to the fcol variable, it is stored as a string. This means that when you try to run it, it would be treated like a string and not a function.
What you did is correct, but you just have to add an `eval()` function so that Python evaluates your `Fore.col` as a function.

```
for col in colors:
    fcol = "Fore." + col
    fcol = eval(fcol)
```

Also, you used the `exec()` function incorrectly in the last line. It should be done like this:

```
print(f"{fcol}[{col}]{Style.RESET_ALL}")
```

A simple way of doing this would be:

```
print(fcol+ col, Style.RESET_ALL)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful and I learned a bit more about eval() and exec().

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
from colorama import Fore, Style

# available foreground colors acquired via dir(Fore)
colors = {
    "BLACK": Fore.BLACK,
    "BLUE": Fore.BLUE,
    "CYAN": Fore.CYAN,
    "GREEN": Fore.GREEN,
    "LIGHTBLACK_EX": Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX,
    "LIGHTBLUE_EX": Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX,
    "LIGHTCYAN_EX": Fore.LIGHTCYAN_EX,
    "LIGHTGREEN_EX": Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX,
    "LIGHTMAGENTA_EX": Fore.LIGHTMAGENTA_EX,
    "LIGHTRED_EX": Fore.LIGHTRED_EX,
    "LIGHTWHITE_EX": Fore.LIGHTWHITE_EX,
    "LIGHTYELLOW_EX": Fore.LIGHTYELLOW_EX,
    "MAGENTA": Fore.MAGENTA,
    "RED": Fore.RED,
    "WHITE": Fore.WHITE,
    "YELLOW": Fore.YELLOW
}

for col in colors:
    print(f"{colors[col]}[{col}]{Style.RESET_ALL}")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get your desired output:

```
from colorama import Fore

colors = [c for c in dir(Fore) if not c.startswith('__')]

for color in colors:
    print( Fore.__getattribute__(color) + f"[{color}]" )
```

[image]